How to create a new column in sql and fill it with an array on python
I've been searching for 6 hours how to do a simple task done with pandas :
postal_id = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, ....]
df_2["postal_id"] = postal_id

Pandas creates a new column in the dataframe, and fills the rows with the values shown just before.
Why can't sql make this easily ?
I created another column primary key id_count = (1, 2, 3...) in order to do :
query = """UPDATE vehicules SET postal_id = %s WHERE id_count = %s;"""
curB.executemany(query, data)

with the mysql.connector library and it cannot do the job in 20 minutes.
Can someone help me on this, im going crazy.
Thank you in advance.

You have to use ALTER TABLE to add a new column. Then you can update it.

Sql shouldn't make this easy. You're changing the schema of a long-term storage solution. As Barmar says, you need ALTER TABLE to make a permanent new column. In pandas, it's just in memory, like adding a key to a dictionary. Once the process ends - the data is gone

It's not helpful for you to think of them as equivalent, despite how the lines get blurred with new tools like DuckDB etc. You're looking for data permanence, to disk.
